# Print an ASCII diamond of asterisks

Tags: java, shapes, ascii-art

My program that prints out a diamond like this:

```
...............*
..........*    *    *
.....*    *    *    *    *
*    *    *    *    *    *    *
.....*    *    *    *    *
..........*    *    *    
...............*
```

But it only works if the parameter or each side of the diamond is `4`. For example if I input `6`, the spacing on the bottom triangle is wrong and I been trying to figure it out.

The bottom triangle doesn't change when the parameter is changed, only the top one does. It only works for input `4`.

```java
public static void printMoreStars(int n) {
    int rowsPrime = 0;

    for (int i = n + 1; i > 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (2 * i) - 1; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int d = 0; d < (2 * rowsPrime) - 1; d++) {
            System.out.print("*" + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(); //new line character

        rowsPrime += 1;
        System.out.println(" ");
    }

    //bottom triangle
    for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (2 * i) + 1; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int d = 0; d < rowsPrime; d++) {
            System.out.print("*" + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(); //new line character

        rowsPrime -= 2;
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made two mistakes when using `rowPrimes`. See my annotations below:

```java
public class Stars {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printMoreStars(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
    }

    public static void printMoreStars(int n) {
        int rowsPrime = 0;

        for (int i = n + 1; i > 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < (2 * i) - 1; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int d = 0; d < (2 * rowsPrime) - 1; d++) {
                System.out.print("*" + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();   //new line character

            rowsPrime += 1;
            System.out.println(" ");
        }

        rowsPrime -= 2; // <- middle line is already printed, so skip that

        //bottom triangle
        for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < (2 * i) + 1; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int d = 0; d < (2 * rowsPrime) - 1; d++) { // <- changed condition to be the same as above
                System.out.print("*" + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();   //new line character

            rowsPrime--; // <- you have to decrease rowPrime by one.
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To print a rhombus with dots on the left, you can use this code.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVG7boMwFN3zFUeeTBFk6NY06hd0acaog0mcYGrsCJtEVcW302vXUoGoUs9yrevzMjTiKgp7kaY5fozjpa@0OuCghXN4FcrgawVC2jsvPI2rVUe0dMt3vlPmvH@H6M4uS@QooL1/q21b9Y4/Zpt4Maz@MpvR6QgzNTvZDnGrsEVhNjSftwgzz6e8gPUaVN5DatnKIDHwtURnbzNacIs88kFBT/V1KSrKTlXvopsU3YTooKQjpc/I0fgEPnFD/uvdZLH2vSZg9@m8bEvb@zJ@DM4eGIk55f0UfQELPIYnMJYtagZI7eQ/rcsAtvBY0rThE8aQ/uAwjt8)

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printRhombus(3);
}
```

```java
public static void printRhombus(int n) {
    for (int i = -n; i <= n; i++) {
        // last element in the row
        int last = n - Math.abs(i);
        for (int j = -n; j <= last; j++)
            if (Math.abs(i) + Math.abs(j) <= n)
                System.out.print("*" + (j < last ? "    " : ""));
            else
                System.out.print(".....");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
...............*
..........*    *    *
.....*    *    *    *    *
*    *    *    *    *    *    *
.....*    *    *    *    *
..........*    *    *
...............*
```

---

<sup>See also: [Print a diamond shape with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68203233/16314724)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Check This:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

class DiamondPattern {
    static public int ReadInteger() {
        try {
            String inpString = "";
            InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);
            String s = reader.readLine();
            return Integer.parseInt(s);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Program for displaying pattern of *.");
        System.out.print("Enter the maximum number of *: ");
        int n = ReadInteger();
        System.out.println("\nHere is the Diamond of Stars\n");
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < (n - i); j++)
                System.out.print(" ");
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                System.out.print("*");
            for (int k = 1; k < i; k++)
                System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < (n - i); j++)
                System.out.print(" ");
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                System.out.print("*");
            for (int k = 1; k < i; k++)
                System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```